# View request text before sending

Tags: ruby, net-http, ruby-1.8.7

I'm using `Net::HTTP` to make a POST request:

```
uri = 'service.example.com'
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri)
https.use_ssl = true
path = "/service_action"
data = request_body_obj.to_json
response = https.post(path, data, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
```

My request is timing out for some reason. To debug why, I'd like to see the text of the request body and headers of my request. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Headers from a Ruby Net::HTTP Request before making the request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900207/getting-headers-from-a-ruby-nethttp-request-before-making-the-request)